# how to find specific line of css code without knowing the path?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

As you can see in de attached link. I'm trying to find this css rule "color: #ffffff !important" so I can delete it:

[css code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1uSL.png)

But for some reason there is no path in the browser development, it only says index and a number of line.

I'm working this on wordpress and divi theme, Any idea how could I find this rule so then I can delete it?

Comment: click on that index .. it's a style added in the html not within a CSS file and knowing wordpress it's for sure an option in the theme that generate this style

Comment: `index` it is inside a `<style>` tag, placed in either `<head>` or `<body>`. The number after it is the actual line number in the source code but, since your page is entirely being generated by the server, it's not going to help you much. From the class names I can already tell you it's your theme. Since ET team are not very orthodox about applying styles and they're well know for overqualified selectors, I suggest you read their ["guide"](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-customize-your-wordpress-css) on how to style your pages.